# Apply function between subsequent rows in more efficient way with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, optimization, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` that is defined like so:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dic = {'A':['1A','1A','3C','3C','3C','7M','7M','7M'],'B':[10,15,49,75,35,33,45,65],'C':[11,56,32,78,45,89,15,14],'D':[111,0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],'E':[0,222,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

My goal is to perform some calculations between rows having the same item in column `A`.

The function is defined like this (but could be anything):

```
def fun(a,b,c,d):
    out = a*c + b/2 + d*b
    return out
```

The result of such operation will be stored in column D and E according to the following rules:

```
# Fill column D
for j in range(0,len(df)-1):
    if df['A'].iloc[j]==df['A'].iloc[j+1] and pd.isnull(df['D'].iloc[j]):
        df['D'].iloc[j] = fun(df['B'].iloc[j],df['B'].iloc[j],df['B'].iloc[j+1],df['B'].iloc[j+1])  

# Fill column E       
for j in reversed(range(1,len(df))):
    if df['A'].iloc[j-1]==df['A'].iloc[j] and pd.isnull(df['E'].iloc[j]):
        df['E'].iloc[j] = fun(df['B'].iloc[j],df['B'].iloc[j],df['B'].iloc[j-1],df['B'].iloc[j-1])
```

Both loops are very similar but the second one is looping from the last element to the first one of the dataframe.
My code works correctly and the result should be like this:

```
          # Before #                         # After #
    A   B   C    D    E          A   B   C       D       E
0  1A  10  11  111    0      0  1A  10  11   111.0     0.0
1  1A  15  56    0  222      1  1A  15  56     0.0   222.0
2  3C  49  32  NaN  NaN      2  3C  49  32  7374.5     NaN
3  3C  75  78  NaN  NaN      3  3C  75  78  5287.5  7387.5
4  3C  35  45  NaN  NaN      4  3C  35  45     NaN  5267.5
5  7M  33  89  NaN  NaN      5  7M  33  89  2986.5     NaN
6  7M  45  15  NaN  NaN      6  7M  45  15  5872.5  2992.5
7  7M  65  14  NaN  NaN      7  7M  65  14     NaN  5882.5
```

Would you be able to improve such code in order to make it more efficient using some build in functions from the Pandas library? I would like to have some more elegant way to achieve my result.

**Note**: the first and second row have already a value (`111 0` and `0 222`) and therefore they must not be calculated by the function!

Comment: Try to use Series.diff

Comment: @user2476373 thanks for the comment :) could you provide me more details on how to use it and why it is suitable for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve my problem I defined another function which takes as input `fun`

```
def fun2(df,s):
    X= fun(df.B,df.C,df.B.shift(s),df.C.shift(s))
    return X
```

Columns `D` and `E` can be filled like so:

```
df2['D']=np.where((df2.A.shift(-1)==df2.A) & (df2.D.isnull()==True),fun2(df2,-1),df2.D) 
df2['E']=np.where((df2.A.shift(1)==df2.A) & (df2.E.shift(1).isnull()==True),fun2(df2,+1),df2.E)
```

**Note**: even though more compact, this approach may be slower

Answer (score 2):

You could first group by the values of A, and then apply a vectorized function :

```
def fun(a,b,c,d):
    out = a*c + b/2 + d*b
    return out

def apply_func(df):
    mask = pd.isnull(df['D'][:-1])
    df['D'][:-1][mask] = fun(df['B'][:-1].values, df['B'][:-1].values, 
                             df['B'][1:].values, df['B'][1:].values)
    mask = pd.isnull(df['E'][1:])
    df['E'][1:][mask] = fun(df['B'][1:].values, df['B'][1:].values, 
                            df['B'][:-1].values, df['B'][:-1].values)
    return df
```

and then :

```
df = df.groupby('A').apply(apply_func).reset_index(drop=True)

    A   B   C       D       E
0  1A  10  11   305.0     NaN
1  1A  15  56     NaN   307.5
2  3C  49  32  7374.5     NaN
3  3C  75  78  5287.5  7387.5
4  3C  35  45     NaN  5267.5
5  7M  33  89  2986.5     NaN
6  7M  45  15  5872.5  2992.5
7  7M  65  14     NaN  5882.5
```

Comment: I also noted that the answer is not correct because the first and second row have fixed values defined within the dictionary (111 0, 0 222)... while your answer is modifying the result

Comment: @FedericoGentile : look at your example DataFrame. Columns D and E have only NaN values. I saw an incongruity between your "Before" and "After" DataFrames, so I just applied the function to the "Before" dataframe. If D and E columns have defined values, the function should not affect them.

Answer (score 1):

you could use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [dataframe.shift()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

- np.where works like an if statement
- datafrmae.shift() - Shift index by desired number of periods with an optional time freq

  ```
   df['D']=np.where(df.A.shift(-1)==df.A,func(df['B'],df['B'],df.B.shift(-1),df.B.shift(-1)),np.NaN)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; what about df['E'] ?

Comment: I also noted that the answer is not correct because the first and second row have fixed values defined within the dictionary (111 0, 0 222)... while your answer is modifying the result

Comment: I was able to fix your answer but df['E'] is still missing